# Why trunk serve doesn't automaticly serve when saving file?

Tags: rust, yew, trunk-rs

I'm using trunk serve in my rust project in Windows, everything goes great and compiles and serves, but if I save the file, it doesn't automactly re-compile and serve.

I was expecting it to when I save any of the rust file it to compile and serve, I did trunk serve and tried trunk serve --watch (filepath).

Any fix?

Comment: According to [trunk's documentation](https://trunkrs.dev/commands/), `trunk serve` should already do what you want. Could you add some more details? It's hard to know what has gone wrong with the information provided.

Comment: The problem is that when I update and save the file trunk serve doesn't build and serve automatically as it should.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm on Windows 11, I've tried to use rust/cargo/trunk both via WSL and natively, both work fine for normal building, but neither rebuilds on a change

Answer (score -2):

***some times native method fails, and theres an alternative approach to do it, and if it was written than there where a purpose to do it.***

**[Install Rust and Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/installation.html)**

**install using Cargo([Binstall](https://github.com/cargo-bins/cargo-binstall/releases)):**
https://crates.io/crates/cargo-watch

cargo install cargo-watch

**recompile when changes are detected:**

cargo watch -x run

**rebuild without running:**

cargo watch -x build

**ignore changes in a directory:**

cargo watch -x run --ignore "directory u want to ignore/*"

**to set up a server u can do this:**

```
cargo new rust_server
cd rust_server
```

**add warp to your `Cargo.toml`:**

```
[dependencies]
warp = "0.3"
```

**than in `src/main.rs`, set up a simple HTTP server:**

```
use warp::Filter;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let hello = warp::path!("hello" / "world")
        .map(|| warp::reply::html("Hello, World!"));

    warp::serve(hello)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 9000))
        .await;
}
```

**and than use this:**

```
cargo watch -x run
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but how I will make it server or at the other words make a http client automaitcly?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I've updated the answer. If not, you can paraphrase this: "make a http client automaitcly?"

Comment: My objective was to run my yew code automatically without needing to be always running trunk serve, I don't add to add any code to my project

Comment: if you will point watcher to your project directory, it will do all the intended stuff you want to do.

Comment: I did trunk serve --watch /src in the root of the project and it compiles and serve but then doesn't do nothing more automatically